# SQL can not find the variable?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I'm creating a script to read a .txt file, I can make it work if I enter the address manually, but in that case I need to create a dynamic address concatenating the location of the file + its name.

I've tried several things like turning the whole procedure into string to execute with the Exec() command, the only way I found it would be concatenating the string in a previously declared variable, the problem is that SQL does not recognize this variable.

```sql
DECLARE @JSON VARCHAR(MAX) -- get json from file

DECLARE @item_name varchar(15) = 'fileName' --random file name from procedure

DECLARE @path varchar(50) = 'C:\Users\Peter\Documents\JsonFiles\'+ @item_name+ '.json' -- path of the file


SELECT @JSON = BulkColumn

FROM OPENROWSET 


(BULK @path , SINGLE_CLOB) --the problem is here, SQL Server can't find @path
AS j...
```

I know I'm forgetting something, I'm just out of ideas for now.

Who can help me, please.

**Edit:** i got the solution, but there is another problem:

After creating the dynamic sql the @item_name worked like a charm, but now if i convert the @JSON like convert(varchar(max),@JSON) the sql variable will be empty, i'm using Print(@sql) to make some tests, and if i do Exec(@sql) nothing happens.

I've shortened the code a bit to fit here, and thanks so much for your time, you guys helped me so much.

```
DECLARE @JSON VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @item_name varchar(15) = 'fileName'
DECLARE @path varchar(60) = 'C:\Users\Peter\Documents\JsonFiles\'+@item_name+'.json'
DECLARE @sql varchar(max)
set @sql =
'
SELECT @JSON = BulkColumn 
FROM OPENROWSET 


(BULK  ' + convert(varchar(60),@path) + ', SINGLE_CLOB) 
AS j

INSERT INTO items
SELECT visible, last_update, item = ' + convert(varchar(15),@item_name) + '
FROM OPENJSON (@JSON , ''$.payload.orders'') 
WITH (   
    visible varchar(7) ''$.visible'',
    last_update datetimeoffset ''$.last_update'',
    item varchar(10) )'

        Print(@sql)
```

Comment: why is c# a tag here?

Comment: `OPENROWSET` requires a literal string, you can't pass a variable for the location.

Comment: Is the server on same machine or different machine?  I do not think the SQL Server can read a user files.  The server is running as a service and doesn't have access to "c:\Users\Peter".  Put file on Network drive where server and user both have access.

Comment: *"I do not think the SQL Server can read a user files"* It *can* , @jdweng , but I suggest against having the Service Account being able to; the file should be stored elsewhere.

Comment: Not always.  I depends on the Credentials.

Comment: Hello and thanks for the tips, i'll try again, and sorry for the tag, I forgot that it's just sql.

Comment: @jdweng is in the same machine, the problem is, i can put only string as adress in (BULK X, SINGLE CLOB), he don't accept variables.

Comment: I think i found the problem, the @JSON can't be converted to varchar(max) or the data will be lost, i'll find another way.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, just declare @JSON after set @sql

```
DECLARE @item_name varchar(15) = 'fileName'
DECLARE @path varchar(60) = 'C:\Users\Peter\Documents\JsonFiles\'+@item_name+'.json'
DECLARE @sql varchar(max)
set @sql =
'
DECLARE @JSON VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @JSON = BulkColumn 
FROM OPENROWSET 


(BULK  ' + convert(varchar(60),@path) + ', SINGLE_CLOB) 
AS j

INSERT INTO items
SELECT visible, last_update, item = ' + convert(varchar(15),@item_name) + '
FROM OPENJSON (@JSON , ''$.payload.orders'') 
WITH (   
    visible varchar(7) ''$.visible'',
    last_update datetimeoffset ''$.last_update'',
    item varchar(10) )'

        Print(@sql)
```